# Not Showing ntfs partitons

Tags: mount, live-usb, windows-10, ntfs

1. Ubuntu ISO loaded on external USB drive.
2. Boot into Ubuntu off external drive via UEFI as a live usb
   These steps work fine. I can also boot into Windows 10 which is installed on the internal hard-drive for the laptop. This is how I know the drive is fine and functioning and the windows partition is actually there and should be accessible.

I tried sudo fdisk -l but didn't see the internal drive listed. So there's nothing showing to mount.
Just looking to see if I missed something or there's something else to try.

Comment: You have a "RAID" or Intel RST mode. Those aren't compatible. If you want to have a dual-boot then you need to install AHCI support in Windows then change the mode to AHCI in UEFI. Then you'll see the other drive.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please see my answer on how to do this.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

**Intel RST**

You've got a single SSD/HDD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD/HDD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

**Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!**

**Source:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
- Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

  - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.